# Do we compete with ServerFault?

Tags: discussion

I just decided to install some snmp daemon on my ubuntu servers.  I tried to start with this site, and searched for snmp. No hits.  I'm exclusively an Ubuntu Linux admin at this point so I figured I'd start at the source.

So then I try the dreaded unix.stackexchange.com. One hit.

Serverfault: 114 hits.

Maybe Ubuntu is about the OS as a desktop. Maybe it's not about things that are sort of general UNIX admin like installing snmp.

Most of what I will need to know about Ubuntu is things like the network stack. How to get Nagios, Cacti, SNPMD, SMTP and other daemony things working.

Should I just hang out at ServerFault?

Comment: OK - well, for my own research I'm going to use all three. When I'm asking something that seems Ubuntu specific, I'll try to bring it here.

Comment: There almost needs to be a apt-get-and-dpkg section somewhere as part of one of these... I find most of my "questions" are "OK, I got xyz all tangled up with apt-get, now what?"

Answer (score 2):

We're primarily desktop orientated here. That doesn't mean there aren't people here that could answer your question but only a portion of the people here to answer questions admin servers and only a portion of them will know what you're talking about.

ServerFault is full of admins. If you need an answer to an adminning question, sure, they're probably a good bet. It's also ***much*** older than AskUbuntu and therefore has a lot more historical postings to find pre-written answers.

You could, of course, help out here and increase the number of people who know to administer Ubuntu servers.

Comment: I don't see why we would limit ourselves to desktop oriented questions. Though I agree the question probably belongs on SF. Perhaps a line to draw is home server vs. things a pro sysadmin would do at work?

Comment: @Jorge I'm not saying anything about limiting ourselves, just what sort of questions fall through here and get answered most often. We have a good record when it comes to answering desktop threads... Just as SF has a good record when it comes to answering server threads.

Answer (score 1):

There is a site for [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) as well, but I see a problem. If no one asks this kind of questions here, they will never appear here and the next person searching will not bei able to find this sort of information.

So, I would recommend asking here and if you do not get an answer, look to other sites and answer your own question here.

Comment: And if you do ask elsewhere, please include links both there and in the AU question so someone can find the other if they find one.

Comment: @Roger Pate: Yes, that would be perfect.